# Maximal distance of set to integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Let $x_1,...,x_N$ be $N$ mutually distinct real numbers.

I wonder: How does the expression

$$ f_x(N)=\sup_{\lambda \in \mathbb R}\min_{i \neq j} \min_{n \in \mathbb Z}\left\vert \lambda (x_i-x_j)-n\right\rvert$$
depend on $N$? I acknowledge the answer might depend on $x$, but I am looking for a lower bound on $\inf_{x; all x_i distinct}f_x(N)$

Let's say we have two numbers, then we can choose $\lambda (x_1-x_2)=1/2.$ Hence, the optimal value in that case is $1/2.$

Comment: Are there specific reasons to look at a difference set rather than e.g. $\sup\min\min|\lambda x_i-n|$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't see why the two are equivalent. Do you?

Comment: They're definitely not equivalent — it just seems to me that the question with individual values rather than differences is a little more 'natural' and I was curious how you came to this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your question is a form of the [Lonely runner conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_runner_conjecture). You can see several results and a summary on that Wikipedia link. An important special case is when the difference of the $x_i$'s are irrational, in which case you can spread them so that you can get arbitrarily close to $1/N$.